# how can i do a 2^20 FFT if the hardware imposes a limit of 2^10 FFT size?

Tags: fft

I need to implement an fft of size `2^20`, but the hardware has imposed a limit of `2^10 fft size`.Then how can i implement the `FFT`. please point me to some literature where i can go through the process

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this ? Normally you would apply a smaller FFT using a sliding window to get a spectrogram, which gives you information about the time-varying nature of your frequency components. It would be unusual to (a) have 2^30 samples which are statistically stationary and (b) to want such a high frequency resolution. Perhaps you could give some background info on your application ?

Comment: Also: 2^20 (title) or 2^30 (question body) ? There's a big difference !

Comment: Sorry for the error and the numericals. I just wanted to know the basic idea of how we proceed when the required FFT size is way higher than the constrained FFT size. Suppose the FFT size is limited to 64 points and i need to measure an FFT size of 2^12. Taking the 64 point FFT and repeating it to get 2^12 FFT seems tedious. I read a technique which uses mixed radix method to do that but i couldnt understand how it is done. Do you have any idea how it is done, and thanx for the reply :)

Comment: OK - see duplicate question: [How to calculate a large size FFT using smaller sized FFTs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940192/how-to-calculate-a-large-size-fft-using-smaller-sized-ffts)

Comment: Which hardware are you talking about, and in which way does it impose a limit on the FFT size?